# Convert JSON date to C# datetime variable

Tags: c#, json

I want to convert my JSON formatted date to C# DateTime variable. Trying to convert it with `Convert.ToDateTime`

> ("2016-01-15T11:44:52-07:00")

is giving me this output

> "1/16/2016 12:14:52 AM"
>   [image]

I am not able to find out whether it is a correct output or not because my input date is 15 Jan 2016 but in output it is 16 Jan 2016.

How can I convert a JSON date value to a C# date value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your current timezone is UTC `+05:30` right now and that's why `Convert.ToDateTime` method adds those value to the result and generates `1/16/2016 00:14:52` as a value.

Since your string has an offset part, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) instead of `Datetime`.

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-01-15T11:44:52-07:00");
```

This will generate `{15.01.2016 11:44:52 -07:00}` as a `DateTimeOffset`.

[image]

But since you said this is related with Json, this technology should have some methods to parse it as well. It would be better to use *those* methods but I'm not familiar with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have problems with the time zones. Try parsing with `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`

```
using System.Globalization;

var s1 = "2016-01-15T11:44:52-07:00";
var date = DateTime.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```